# Can you please explain difference between tracert and whois result?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am running tracert on a site hosted on webfaction. The last line shows

```
web106.webfaction.com
```

But, when I run jwhois 108.59.4.95 on linux of the same site, I get

```
Websmart LTD WEBSMART (NET-108-59-4-32-1) 108.59.4.32 - 108.59.4.95
Leaseweb USA, Inc. LEASEWEB-US (NET-108-59-0-0-1) 108.59.0.0 - 108.59.15.255
```

So, what does the jwhois information indicate? Does webfaction leases server from the above 2 organisations?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tracert` shows the hostname of a computer - `web106.webfaction.com`.  This is a computer named  `web106` on the domain `webfaction.com`.  (Incidentally, this hostname resolves to `108.59.4.67`, not the address you ran a `whois` against.)

[A `whois` query returns information on who the registered user is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois).

> WHOIS (pronounced as the phrase who is) is a query and response protocol that is widely used for querying databases that store the registered users or assignees of an Internet resource, such as a domain name, an IP address block, or an autonomous system, but is also used for a wider range of other information.

In you case, this returned the information that [Leaseweb USA, Inc.](http://www.leaseweb.com/en/contact) is the owner/assignee of a large IP block, some of which they've in turn leased out to Websmart LTD, which is also a webhost.  (I got a malware warning on their homepage, so I'm not linking that here.) And, yes, as `web106.webfaction.com` is in Websmart LTD's IP block, that computer is hosted by Websmart, LTD.

Answer (score 0):

whois has nothing to do with dns, it merely shows the "owner" of ip ranges or domains and does not limit the names that can be assigned to ip addresses in any way.

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean ""owner" of ip ranges or domains"?

Comment: @John IP addresses are owned by entities the same way domains are, though the two systems are entirely separate. The IP address for web106.webfaction.com is owned by an entity known as Websmart LTD, which may or may not be the same entity that owns 'webfaction.com'.

Comment: In case of domains: the one who registered the domain. In case of IP addresses: the one who the IP address has been assigned to by a local registry such as RIPE, or ARIN.